# how to use collectionView Cell horizontally in swift4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

[![enter image description here][1]][1][![enter image description here][2]][2]I am using the `collectionView` cells horizontally to getting JSON data but the problem is I'm using the cell size height 100 and the width is `view` of the screen with paging enabled, but the problem is I can scroll it but I want to get edges 20 spacing of leading and trailing. I'm moving the cells cant get the cell edges of leading and trailing like the first cell

```
class MainContainer: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionview: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var FlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: (self.view.frame.width - 20), height: 100)
}
```

Comment: no bro its not working

Comment: Please add your layout screenshot.

Comment: How to upload multiple pictures

Comment: Same way you have added first image.

Comment: No shall I add now

Comment: bro i had upload picture

Comment: what is width of you collectionView?

Comment: Width is self.view.frame.size.width -20

Comment: collectionView is same as cell? i am asking UICollectionView size that you have added in storyboard. what constraint you have gave?

Comment: Width 355 in iPhone 8 size I given leading 10 and trailing 10

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the minimum spacing in collectionView for cell as well as line

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Comment: yeah the cell is getting close but. i want like amazon collection view cell

Comment: put in your question.

Comment: or you can set it's to 4 or 5

Comment: first cell is working nice if i moving to second cell looks like this

Comment: please. help me out bro

Comment: you also need to add method like 

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = (self.view.frame.size.width - 20)
    let height = yourheight
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}

Comment: try this and tell me it's Work or not.

Comment: also add my method?

Comment: add method that i ansered the question

Comment: Bro the problem is I’m scrolling the cell it’s getting like I uploaded the pic like that

Comment: i am understand your problem can you try to put that method that i am writing??

Comment: Yes bro still I’m getting same issue

Comment: it's same or some minore changed?

Answer (score 0):

try in viewDidLoad() in your controller, as layout changes programmatically , so it overrides the default value for scrolling direction

```
FlowLayout.scrolldirection = .horizontal
```

Comment: its saying not the member of scrollview direction

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.width - 20), height: 100)
}
```

Comment: bro same issue like 2nd picture

Answer (score 0):

**Step - 1 :  ** Create CollectionView in StoryBoard (height,width,min-spacing,left-right)

**Step - 2 :  ** import (UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout)

**Step - 3 :  **

```
@IBOutlet var collViewFeaturedEvents: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet var collViewEventsHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

**Step - 4 :  ** Implement Methods

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        if collectionView == self.collViewEvents
        {
            return self.ArrEvent.count
        }
    }


     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
        {

           {
```

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollCell", for: indexPath) as! CollCell
//            let Listingimage = self.ArrListing[indexPath.item]["url"].stringValue
           return cell
                cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
                cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.5, height: 2.5)
                cell.layer.shadowRadius = 5
                cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
                cell.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

```
            let Listingimage = self.ArrListing[indexPath.item]["url"].stringValue
            print(Listingimage)
            let ImageUrl = URL_IMAGES.listing_logo+Listingimage

            cell.lblTitle?.text = self.ArrListing[indexPath.item]["business_name"].stringValue
            cell.lblDesc?.text = self.ArrListing[indexPath.item]["slogan"].stringValue
            cell.Imagview?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: ImageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "splash screen-test-compress.jpg"), options: [.continueInBackground,.lowPriority], completed: {(image,error,cacheType,url) in

                if error == nil
                {
                    cell.Imagview?.image = image
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.Imagview?.image =  UIImage(named: "splash screen-test-compress.jpg")
                }
            })
        }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
let size = CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.size.width - 30)/2.5, height: 150)
            return size
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
let strId = self.ArrListing[indexPath.item]["id"].stringValue
            let detailVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListingDetails_InnerVC") as! ListingDetails_InnerVC
            detailVC.strID = strId
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
    }
```

> self.collViewFeaturedEventsHeight.constant = self.collViewFeaturedEvents.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
>                                   self.view.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()